# Backbone nested view has events which are not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Okay so I have a parent view which has a click event which renders a child view. Within this child view is a form which I'm trying to validate and then submit. So my parent view looks something like this:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.body',
    template: _.template(MapTemplate),
    render: function() {
        ...
    },
    events: {
        'click #log-pane-title': 'loadLogView'
    },
    loadLogView: function() {
        var eventLogView = new EventLogView({
            id: properties._id
        });

        eventLogView.render();
    }
});
```

And my child view looks something like this:

```
var EventLogView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#eventlog',
    logform: new NewLogForm({
                template: _.template(AddLogTemplate),
                model: new LogModel()
            }).render(),
    render: function() {
        // Render the form
        $("#addtolog").html(this.logform.el);
    },
    events: {
        'submit #addlogentry': 'test'
    },
    test: function() {
        alert('inside eventlogview');
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem I'm facing is that `test()` never fires. For debugging purposes I made sure the submit event was even firing by putting:

```
$('#addlogentry').on('submit', function() { 
    alert( "submit firing" ); 
    return false; 
});
```

In `render()` of the `EventLogView`. That does actually trigger, so I'm not sure what's going on and why `test()` isn't triggering.

Comment: The backbone events are scoped to the views el. So is your `#addlogentry` live inside your `EventLogView` "view"? So in your case the proper test would be: `this.$el.on('submit', '#addlogentry', function() { `

Comment: @nemesv That's what it was! Post this as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid scoping issues **all the `events` delegation are scoped to the views `el`** in Backbone.

So your `#addlogentry` button should live inside your `EventLogView` `el`.

And your sanity check in the `render` should look something like this to mimic how Backbone works internally :

```
this.$el.on('submit', '#addlogentry', function() { 
    alert( "submit firing" ); 
    return false; 
});
```